# Laravel 4 array to string conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I tried to ran a query, but it returns an `Array to string conversion` error. I can't fix it, I tried several things, but didn't locate the error.

```
<td>{{ DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT * FROM `player_deaths` WHERE `player_id`='.$s->id.' order by `time` DESC LIMIT 0, 10') ); }}</td>
```

Comment: Best solution is to NOT put db logic into a view. If you move that to a controller (or better, a [repository](http://vimeo.com/53029232) class). That'll give you ample opportunity to handle the situation when you get no results returned and don't have an array to pass to your view, which is part of the issue you're working through with Gadoma below.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query in a neater way, like that:

```
DB::table('player_deaths')->where('player_id', '=', $s->id)->orderBy('time', 'desc')->skip(0)->take(10)->get()->toArray();
```

And you get the error because you want to print out an array. Instead you should iterate over it in a foreach loop.

```
@foreach (DB::table('player_deaths')->where('player_id', '=', $s->id)->orderBy('time', 'desc')->skip(0)->take(10)->get() as $death) 
<td> {{ $death }} </td>
@endforeach
```

In general, what are you trying to do here ?

Traditionally, Read The Manual man ... it's all there.

http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries
http://four.laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating

Comment: Getting an new error: `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object` - what I'm trying to do is to retrieve all the player deaths from player_deaths table that have the player's id.

Comment: this means the query returns no rows. Im editing answer, try without the toarray and let me know.

Comment: new one : `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: try this: var_dump((DB::table('player_deaths')->where('player_id', '=', $s->id)->orderBy('time', 'desc')->skip(0)->take(10)->get()) and edit your answer to include the result.

Comment: I can't use the var_dump because my $s->id is used only in the view lol.